# Unable to download com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.5.6 with sbt

Tags: maven, sbt

I'm getting the following error when building my project:

`[warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.5.6/paranamer-2.5.6.pom: invalid sha1: expected=534448ad3c4af760c8995370c1405b9dbf88609e computed=0d33f7748ec6c8928db74f9652a2cb7567fe4044 (116ms)
[warn]  module not found: com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.5.6`

This is a transitive dependency, which I was able to download previously. I got this error when I wiped my ~/.ivy2/cache dir. 
Not really sure what has changed with this depenency. When I look [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer), nothing has changed in 2.5.6 since 2013.

What can be the cause of this and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Paranamer here. I've no idea why this happened. Could be related to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-16113

- Paul

Comment: Yeah, looks like it could be the same issue. I will keep an eye on that issue. Thanx